# Modelmapper to convert objects: from Tuple to AnyClass

Tags: java, tuples, modelmapper

I have a method that returns a Tuple type object, with the values: category type Category and total type BigDecimal.

How do I implement a modelMapper method to map the Tuple to a Product type class with the two attributes (category - type Category and total - type BigDecimal)?

How to implement this method to convert a Tuple object of n values to any other object with n corresponding attributes?

How to implement this method in the case of `List<Tuple>` to `List <AnyClass>`?

In the case of `List<Tuple>` to `List<Product>`, I have the following piece of functional code. It is incomplete, it just maps the first attribute, in the case of category.

Note: productsTuple is a type of `List<Tuple>` object returned from a repository.

```
List<Product> products = productsTuple
            .stream()
            .map(p -> modelMapper.map(p.get(0), Produto.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. (Fixed up)

```
List<Product> products = productsTuple
            .stream()
            .map(p -> {
                Map<String, Object> maps = new HashMap<>();
                p.getElements().forEach(te -> {
                    maps.put(te.getAlias(), p.get(te.getAlias()));
                });
                return modelMapper.map(maps, Product.class));
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. With the fix below it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a small compile error. Also, this works only if you set an alias.

It should be

```
            List<Product> products = tupleResult
                    .stream()
                    .map(p -> {
                        Map<String, Object> maps = new HashMap<>();
                        p.getElements().forEach(te -> {
                            maps.put(te.getAlias(), p.get(te.getAlias()));
                        });
                        return modelMapper.map(maps, Product.class);
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```